# How does one graph the "unit tangential vector field" given by the function F = <-y, x>/r?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I know how to graph a vector field in general , the tail starts at the x,y coordinate of the domain of the function F and then you draw the corresponding 
vector produced by the function F. The field appears to be vectors all of the same length  pointing in a counter clock wise fashion and in a circular manner  but I cannot understand how this is done? It seems the vectors would be of different sizes , anybody out there with experience graphing vector fields ?

Comment: Why would they be of different sizes? You're _normalising_ each individual vector to a length of $1$.

Comment: I thought of that but could not figure out how F=<-y,x>/r normalized a vector.  I don't see the norm symbol in the F function  , it maps to -y , x divided by some constant r ,no, where is the unit vector ?

Comment: You're dividing by $r = \sqrt{(-y)^{2} + x^{2}}$..

Comment: oh....sorry....when you divide you get the norm ...  I missed that. I will delete the question after you read my apology

Comment: No need to apologise mate, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tacitly assumed here that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>0$. Therefore we may as well write
$${\bf F}=\langle-{y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},{x\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\rangle=\langle-\sin\phi,\cos\phi\rangle={\bf u}_{\phi+\pi/2}\ ,$$
where $\phi$ denotes the polar angle of $(x,y)$ and ${\bf u}_\phi:=\langle\cos\phi,\sin\phi\rangle$ denotes the unit vector in direction $\phi$.